# C++ Instance new Lua table with __index

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, lua

I was trying to create exemplar of table in C++ which is defined in Lua. In short, i was trying to rewrite this behavior in C++

```
function Account:new (o)
    o = o or {}   -- create object if user does not provide one
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index = self
    return o
end

int FLua::CreateTable(const char* name)
{
    LogLua(ELogVerbosity::Warning, "Creating new exemplar of table", name);

    lua_createtable(L, 0, 1);
    luaL_getmetatable(L, name);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "__index");

    int index = luaL_ref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);

    return index;
}
```

This code doesnt work.

Comment: Your code does the equivalent of `o.__index = self`

Comment: Executing functions of that table even with pcall gives me instacrash without error string, only error code 2.

Comment: Do this looks ok? 
`lua_rawgeti(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, table_index);
lua_getfield(L, -1, func_name);
lua_pcall(FLua::State(), 0, 1, 0);
return lua_toboolean(L, -1) == 1;`

Comment: See [luaL_setmetatable](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#luaL_setmetatable)

Comment: I have no such API, I am using LuaJit 5.1.3